# how to change the freq to 48kHz during RTP streaming in pulseaudio

Tags: gstreamer, pulseaudio

*While streaming rtp packets i want to change the frequency to 48kHz by default max freq is 44.1kHz is there any api to directly do it in pulseaudio ???*

Comment: plz show us what u have tried

Comment: just modified this api pa_context_load_module(context, module-rtp-send, source=rtp.monitor destinatio=107.134.242.242 port=32342 rate= 48000, index_callback, NULL) ...but its not working

Answer (score 0):

You can set many parameters in Gstreamer one of them is the **Clock-rate** which in this case is the same as your frequency:

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v udpsrc port=5000 ! "application/x-rtp,media=(string)audio, 
clock-rate=(int)44100, width=16, height=16, encoding-name=(string)L16,
encoding-params=(string)1, channels=(int)1, channel-positions=(int)1, 
payload=(int)96" ! rtpL16depay ! audioconvert ! alsasink sync=false
```

You can change the integer after **clock-rate** to any value you desire.